# Do the trace and norm always belong to the base field?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, trace

Let $F$ be a field and $E$ be a finite field extension of $F$. Let's call $F$ the base field.

Do the two following proposition involving [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm) and [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_trace) hold?

1. $\forall u \in F, N_{E/F}(u) \in F$.
2. $\forall u \in F, \operatorname{Tr}_{E/F}(u) \in F$.

I have found some results like this, but it seems that always require the extension to be separable, or normal, or both. I would like to know if these proposition hold in general, just supposing that the extension is finite.

Comment: The norm and trace are the determinant and trace of the regular representation.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown so, all the entries of that matrix belong to $F$, and consequently, the norm and the trace belong to $F$? Thank you for commenting.